# Redirecting directly from phoenix router

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to redirect from my router.ex.

I'm got something like:

```
import Phoenix.Controller, only: [redirect: 2]

scope("/", MyApp) do
  forward "/test", :redirect, to: "/new-url"
end
```

The current error I'm getting is:

```
== Compilation error in file lib/myapp_web/router.ex ==
** (ArgumentError) expected an Elixir module, got: "redirect"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Phoenix.Router.forward/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Router.html?#forward/4) expects **a plug** as the second parameter.

Outside of any scope add the line:

```
forward "/test", MyApp.NewUrl
```

where `MyApp.NewUrl` is either a [plug module](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/readme.html) or a phoenix controller.

Comment: Can I not use Phoenix.Controller.redirect here? Or do I need to define a new controller just to implement the redirect?

Comment: Phoenix.Controller.redirect is a plug, if I understood correctly

Comment: `forward` expects [a module plug](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/routing.html#forward). The implementation that calls [`Phoenix.Controller.redirect/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#redirect/2) is literally a one-liner.